# Executing Tex Live by SSH command

Tags: installing, texlive, ubuntu, linux

I installed Tex Live by apt-get on Ubuntu, and I could access to latex commands both in Terminal and in web scripts; e.g. in PHP by `shell_exec('pdflatex -version');`

On a similar machine, I installed from source. I put PATH both in my user and /etc/profile. I could access to latex with all users (including my web user) in Terminal; but in web scripts I get error `pdflatex: not found`.

How apt-get make latex commands globally available on the machine, and what should I do so with installation from source?

Comment: This looks more like an Ubuntu issue than a TeX one.  If you want to see what apt-get does besides just installing a package, get hold of the deb file and do `dpkg -e deb-file` then look at the created file `DEBIAN/postinst`.  That'll explain what extras are done after the package is installed, such as setting paths and so forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try creating symlinks in standard locations with `tlmgr path add`: this will create symlinks for the executables in `/usr/local/bin` which is hopefully in the path of every user. You can adjust the location of the symlinks with `tlmgr option sys_bin <value>` *before* creating the symlinks.

If this doesn't work, there's nothing more you can try on the TeX Live side of things, so you'd better ask on serverfault or something how to set the path for your web server.